# Sort nested dictionary across multiple keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I want all dictionary values in ascending order.

My dictionary, `df`, looks like the following:

```
df = {("A",): {"a": {"a1": 0.5, "a2": 0.2, "a3":1.0}},
      ("B",): {"b1": 0.8, "b2": 0.4}}
```

My ideal output would be:

```
A⇨
　a→a2:0.2
B⇨
　b2→0.4
A⇨
　a→a1:0.5
　　・
　　・
　　・
```

I wrote this:

```
for key,value in sorted(df.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

But when I run it, the dictionary is sorted by alphabetical　order.. Rewriting like `key=lambda x:x[1]` raises `KeyError`.

How can I do this?

Comment: so you want to sort across multiple keys?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes,ido

Comment: are you sure `df` is like you show it and not like `df = {("A",): {"a": {"a1": 0.5, "a2": 0.2, "a3":1.0}}, ("B",): {"b1": 0.8, "b2": 0.4}}`? Is `("B", )` contained in `("A", )`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You are right,df is `df = {("A",): {"a": {"a1": 0.5, "a2": 0.2, "a3":1.0}}, ("B",): {"b1": 0.8, "b2": 0.4}}` I edit my info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd flatten the `dict` first, then sort it. Something like:

```
def flatten_dict(d_in, d_out, parent_key):
    for k, v in d_in.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_dict(v, d_out, parent_key + (k,))
        else:
            d_out[parent_key + (k,)] = v


df = {("A",): {"a": {"a1": 0.5, "a2": 0.2, "a3":1.0}},
    ("B",): {"b1": 0.8, "b2": 0.4}}

d_out = {}

flatten_dict(df, d_out, tuple())

print(d_out)

for key, value in sorted(d_out.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

This way, you can still use it to look values up by their flattened key.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a recursive function to turn the dictionary into a list of tuples like:

```
 (('A',), 'a', 'a1', 0.5), (('A',), 'a', 'a2', 0.2), (('A',), 'a', 'a3', 1.0), ...
```

And then sort this list of tuples:

```
def dict_to_list(input_dict):
    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for nested_value in dict_to_list(value):
                yield (key, ) + nested_value
        else:
            yield (key, value)

print(sorted(dict_to_list(df), key=lambda value: value[-1]))


>>> [(('A',), 'a', 'a2', 0.2), (('B',), 'b2', 0.4), (('A',), 'a', 'a1', 0.5), (('B',), 'b1', 0.8), (('A',), 'a', 'a3', 1.0)]
```